# TCP Window size libnids

Tags: tcp, libpcap

My intent is to write a app. layer process on top of libnids. The reason for using libnids API is because it can emulate Linux kernel TCP functionality. Libnids would return hlf->count_new which the number of bytes from the last invocation of TCP callback function. However the tcp_callback is called every time a new packet comes in, therefore hlf->count_new contains a single TCP segment.

However, the app. layer is supposed to receive the TCP window buffer, not separate TCP segments.

Is there any way to get the data of the TCP window (and not the TCP segment)? In other words, to make libnids deliver the TCP window buffer data.

thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't understand how this could possibly work. The TCP connection already has an application on the end of it (the application that is listening on the port) and I don't see how one TCP connection could have two applications at the same endpoint. Which one decides what data to send to the other side?

Comment: The application that I am referring to is passive to the TCP connection. For example, an HTTP object re-constructor. My process reads the interface (or packet trace), and tries to determine how many bytes have been send in an HTTP transaction. However, I do not want to add seperate TCP segment, but rather the TCP buffers. The question is how can I get the TCP buffer size? Let me know if this clearer.

Comment: That's an internal detail of the other TCP stack that's talking to the active application. You would have to look inside that other TCP stack to know. (Just like an eavesdropping mailman can tell what letters you get and what letters you send, but not whether you've read a letter or not.) From your vantage point, you cannot tell if the other application has asked for the data from the other TCP stack.

Comment: But I thought the eavesdropping libnids could read the "Window Size" field in the TCP header, and determine the window size. The receiver specifies the receive window, therefore the eavesdropping libnids is aware of the amount of bytes it will potentially read. Then it looks for the ACK exchange to determine the actual bytes send. Am I missing something?

Comment: What you're missing is that the window size is negotiated between the two TCP stacks based on what has been received *by* *those* *TCP* *stacks*, not by the applications they are talking to. It's designed to regulated the amount of data 'in flight', not the amount buffered at the endpoints. When an applications reads from a TCP stack, most of the time, **nothing** is sent on the wire to reflect that.

Comment: I understand your points and thank you for getting back. But, I cannot still get why the libnids sniffer is not able to see TCP windows. Lets say H1 sends SYN to H2. H2 replies with a SYN/ACK and sets the initial window size. The sniffer reads the TCP header of the SYN/ACK and is aware that H2 has requested N packets. H1 sends N packets, and the sniffer reads N packets. Those N packets are kept in the sniffer buffer. H2 receives the N packets, sends an ACK, and doubles the TCP window. The sniffer gets ACK, and is awre of the window size. Where is my mistake? I really appreciate your help!

Comment: You are confusing the window with the application buffer. The application buffer holds data not yet read by the application. The window holds data not yet acknowledged by the receiving TCP stack. You are assuming that an application read triggers a TCP window change. It may, but most commonly it does not. (And since the other end doesn't care, it would be wasteful to send a TCP packet just to change the window when there's still enough space left.) You already get to see each byte of data once, and there's no more than that you can do.

Comment: I think I got it... For every app call of the sniffer, the app is going to read data from the app buffer. The app buffer receives data from the TCP on a per segment basis (<MTU), not on a per TCP window basis (sometimes >MTU). This is because the sniffer cannot passively determine the TCP window of the end-hosts. Once again thanks for the answers!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a misunderstanding. The TCP window is designed to control the amount of data in flight. Application reads do not always trigger TCP window changes. So the information you seek is not available in the place you are looking.

Consider, for example, if the window is 128KB and eight bytes have been sent. The receiving TCP stack must acknowledge those eight bytes regardless of whether the application reads them or not, otherwise the TCP connection will time out. Now imagine the application reads a single byte. It would be pointless for the TCP stack to enlarge the window by one byte -- and if window scaling is in use, it *can't* do that even if it wants to.

And then what? If four seconds later the application reads another single byte, adjust the window again? What would be the point?

The purpose of the window is to control data flow between the two TCP stacks, prevent the buffers from growing infinitely, and control the amount of data 'in flight'. It only indirectly reflects what the application has read from the TCP stack.

It is also strange that you would even want this. Even if you could tell what had been read by the application, of what possible use would that be to you?

Comment: My question is not if the application changes the TCP window. I understand that this does not happen, as it would violate the layering principle. Lets modify your example a bit. Assume that the TCP has acknowledged 6KB. Then there is an app call. The app can get at most 6KB. Is this right? If it is, then I want my sniffer app. to get those 6KB (and not each independent acknowledged TCP segment from the TCP layer).

Comment: But you did get those 6KB already. If you want them again, just save them somewhere.

Comment: Since 6KB has been acknowledged by the end host, I am expecting libnids to know that and deliver 6KB. Libnids does not deliver 6KB, it just delivers the 6KB broken into segments (therefore ~5 calls). My question is how can my app can get the 6KB in one call, not multiple ones. Sorry for making this post too long...

Comment: Every time your callback gets called, add the data to a buffer. When your app makes a call, give it all the data in the buffer.